# JOIN ids with 0 as a parent ids, to a query of ids that have distinct parent ids

Tags: mysql, join, distinct

I'm trying to make a list of user related discussions.

Imagine, if you will:

```
posts
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ID | PID | FID | TITLE                                    | USER
1  |  0  |  1  | Hello World                              | User 1
2  |  0  |  23 | Endangered Squirrels & How to Cook Them  | Eddy
3  |  1  |  1  | Re: Hello World                          | Eddy
4  |  1  |  1  | Re: Hello World                          | Clark
5  |  0  |  3  | Any Vacation Suggestions?                | Clark
6  |  5  |  3  | Re: Any Vacation Suggestions?            | Eddy
7  |  5  |  3  | Re: Any Vacation Suggestions?            | Clark
8  |  5  |  3  | Re: Any Vacation Suggestions?            | Ellen
```

To show all of Eddy's posts I was using a query selecting posts with **DISTINCT parents ids(pid)** and thought it was working. I soon realized that 0 was only consider DISTINCT once and if he had created a new topic and not replied, it wasn't being listed if it wasn't his first.

So how do I get a list of ids with  **DISTINCT pid** and pid != 0, and join it with a query of ids that have **pid = 0 where the user = Eddy**

This is the first question I've ever asked so forgive me if it's not perfect.

**UPDATED WITH QUERY**

*I have since switched to using GROUP BY so I can fetch the post's id, but the issue is still the same*

I was asked to provide my query. This is the one I'm using that only provides 1 row with pid as 0. I also updated my table layout above to show forum id, in the query below it only pulls topics from a list of public forums.

```
SELECT id, pid FROM posts WHERE fid IN (1,2,3) AND author = 'Eddy' GROUP BY pid ORDER BY IF(latest > timestamp, latest, timestamp) DESC LIMIT 1, 5;
```

thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Post your query as well.

Comment: Instead of trying to describe code in natural language, show the actual code. You might be interested in learning [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try to look at the following answers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query I think it's the same.

Comment: It's similar, but I'm not looking for ALL children. I want the ids of every parent the author created, as well as 1 child id - that the author created -  per parent.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what I wanted with a simple **IF** in the **GROUP BY**, it was so simple.

```
SELECT id, pid
FROM posts
WHERE fid IN (1,2,3)
AND author = 'Eddy'
GROUP BY IF(pid > 0, pid, id)
ORDER BY IF(latest > timestamp, latest, timestamp) DESC
LIMIT 1, 5;
```